# Lead Lag function not working on Teradata 15.0 .Any alternative method that could give me similar results

Tags: join, teradata, lag, teradata-sql-assistant, lead

MY TABLE
[DATABASE TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNbvq.png)

I am trying to find the variance between Next In date to Previous out date on EMPL level.
Something like this
[OUTPUT Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7DXs.png)

The Lag Code i tried using is

SELECT  CUSTID_DIV,
CUSTID_MASTER,
CUSTID_KEY,
TENURE_DAYS,
LAG(TENURE_DAYS  ,'1','0')
OVER ( PARTITION  BY CUSTID_MASTER  ORDER BY CUSTID_MASTER ) AS TEST
FROM    BSYBI_SLSOPS.CUSTOMER_ANALYTICS_V

ERROR: DATA TYPE "TENURE DAYS" does not match the defined data type.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of the LEAD/LAG code and also any error messages produced?

Comment: My teradata sql assistant is old version so doesn't support lad and lead functions SELECT CUSTID_DIV,
  CUSTID_MASTER,
  CUSTID_KEY,
  TENURE_DAYS,
  LAG(TENURE_DAYS  ,'1','0')
     OVER ( PARTITION  BY CUSTID_MASTER  ORDER BY CUSTID_MASTER ) AS TEST
FROM TABLEV

 Error:  Data type "tenure days" does not match the defined data type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC (I might not), LEAD/LAG wasn't fully implemented until 16.  So try:

```
MAX(COALESCE(TENURE_DAYS,0)) OVER ( PARTITION BY CUSTID_MASTER ORDER BY CUSTID_MASTER ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
```

The pattern is: `MAX(<column>) OVER (PARTITION BY <column(s)> ORDER BY <column(s)> ROWS BETWEEN 1 <PRECEDING (Lag)/FOLLOWING (Lead)> AND 1 <PRECEDING (Lag)/FOLLOWING (Lead)>)`

Comment: Thank you for the quick inputs here SELECT CUSTID_DIV,
  CUSTID_MASTER,
  CUSTID_KEY,
  TENURE_DAYS,
  
  MAX(CAST (COALESCE(TENURE_DAYS,0) as VARCHAR)) OVER ( PARTITION BY CUSTID_MASTER ORDER BY CUSTID_MASTER ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
FROM BSYBI_SLSOPS.CUSTOMER_ANALYTICS_V
                                    ERROR: Expected something like '(' between the 'VARCHAR' Keyword and ')'

Comment: You'll need to specify the width of VARCHAR

Comment: @SanketGandhi I have no idea why I threw `CAST` in there in the first place (was that from an earlier edit?) - what is the data type of `Tenure_Days` and what do you want it to be?

Comment: I would like to use date probably to make query efficient. can i use date ? or it would be days . [Tenure days is decimal datatype]

Comment: MAX(COALESCE(CAST(NEXT_LC_DATE AS VARCHAR(10)),'Date is NULL')) OVER ( PARTITION BY CUSTID_MASTER ORDER BY CREATED_DATETIME  ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) This worked... Thank you so much for the help here :)

Comment: The COALESCE should be outside of the MAX:`COALESCE(CAST(
MAX(NEXT_LC_DATE) 
OVER ( PARTITION BY CUSTID_MASTER 
       ORDER BY CREATED_DATETIME
       ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS VARCHAR(10)),'Date is NULL')`, but why do you CAST anyway, what's the additional benefit vs. a simple NULL?